# MP3 playback issues with DirectX when MP3 has album art encoded

Tags: delphi, directx, mp3, directsound

I'm using the Clootie DirectShow9 headers with Delphi 2007.  I created a wrapper component that plays audio and video. All is good until I get an MP3 that has album art encoded in it. The mp3 files like this just will not play.  I do not get an error message from my code when I call pMediaControl.Run;.  pMediaControl is IMediaControl.  They just do not start playing. I many other MP3 files that are not encoded with album art and they play fine. There must be something I'm missing but I cannot figure it out.

These art encoded mp3 files play OK in WMP and Winamp on the same PC.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks

Comment: After some digging in my code it seems that the call to **hr:= pGraphBuilder.RenderFile(FFileName,nil);** 
is where the problem occurs.  After this the value of hr is -2147220890 which looks like it means VFW_E_NO_TRANSPORT.

Answer (score 1):

I have also hit that one (or was it VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM). 
It's because the metadata is currupted, or when the image-size is very big.
(editing the Tag in Winamp sometimes helps)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately editing the files is not an option. The application is part media player and must be able to play customer mp3 files with album art without altering the files.

Comment: You could try Media Foundation, if that's an option. It's doint a better job at handling those "wierd" files

Comment: I read a little about Media Foundation and it and look like it is available only on Vista and up.  I need Windows XP support for now.
I'm going to use the bass.dll and the delphi wrapper unit.  I've done some testing already and all my problem mp3 files play with bass.  

I wanted to stay away from using a third party component / dll but time to finish this project is getting slim.

http://www.un4seen.com

The download includes many Delphi samples.  So far the library has worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I read a little about Media Foundation and it and look like it is available only on Vista and up.  I need Windows XP support for now.

I'm going to use the bass.dll and the delphi wrapper unit.  I've done some testing already and all my problem mp3 files play with bass.

I wanted to stay away from using a third party component / dll but my time to finish this project is getting slim.

http://www.un4seen.com

The download includes many Delphi samples.  So far the library has worked great.